# ArrayDeque is implemented as an array, why is it not Random Access?

Tags: java, arrays, list, deque, arraydeque

I know that **ArrayDeque** is fast when adding and removing simple lists.
I tested it, it was quicker to add and delete than LinkedList.
Because I know that it is implemented as an Array, so why not Random Access?

I read the ArrayDeque.java file in the Java src. But I do not understand it well with my English level. I've seen a lot of articles from Google and Stack Overflow, but I did not get the answers I wanted.

In conclusion, what I'm looking for is:

1. **Why is ArrayDeque not Random Access?** (I am most curious)
2. In what situations is ArrayDeque used?
3. Is ArrayDeque not implemented as an Array? (Did I misunderstand this?)

Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: There were plans to retrofit `ArrayDeque` to implement the `List` interface (or just to implement some `List`-related methods), but I'm not sure if it's being discussed actively: https://markmail.org/message/tdp2hjhsuknfthrf?q=net.java.openjdk&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+MarkmailNetjavaopenjdk+%28Follow+OpenJDK+development+e-mail+traffic%29#query:net.java.openjdk+page:1+mid:ao3xupqbbafdoax6+state:results

Comment: Do I need to point out that you're intended to program against the interface (in this case, `Deque`) rather than the implementation?  As for performance, `ArrayDeque` is faster at some operations while `LinkedList` is faster at others.... and `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` is the only one that's thread-safe out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), ArrayDeque is resizable-array implementation of the Deque interface. Underlining data-structure is Array. However, it doesn't support random access because it exposes double-ended queue interface. If you want to access a random element of Deque, you can invoke `toArray()` and then access elements by index.

Comment: Thank you for answer. If I want to use Random Access in ArrayDeque, is it better to just use ArrayList? If I were to use the toArray() method?

Comment: `toArray()` has the drawback that it sets all the values in an array, so it's O(N). I have [an alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75584860/1889018), which should be O(1). I did a few measurements, and `toArray()` is faster for a relatively small size of an `ArrayDeque`, but it is significantly slower with larger sizes (millions or more). Of course, usage patterns matter a lot too. What surprised me is that the variant of `toArray()` that uses a preallocated array seems always slower than the one that creates a new array.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is that there's no good reason.  It would be easy to add a constant-time `get(int)` and `set(int,E)` to `ArrayDeque`.   More than once I've had to implement the algorithms of `ArrayDeque` within an `ArrayList` to make up for that lack.

Comment: There is an issue open for this, although it isn't getting much attention: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143850

Comment: Yeah, that change request asks for too much.

Comment: There would be very good reasons for it. I've just bumped into a case where I need to sum up some elements in the queue (and even do a weighted sum). Fortunately, Kotlin was smarter than to say there's no reason for it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to *"why there is no random access"* is that it didn't seem necessary when the class was created, and also it sort of doesn't make sense: `ArrayDeque` is firstly a kind of `Deque`, which is something mainly allowing access at both ends and that's about it. So I sort of agree that a random access function shouldn't be in `Deque` (though, by the same logic, it shouldn't be in `List` either). You can also have `ArrayDeque` implementing `List`, as others pointed out, but it's hard to retrofit and perhaps there are other issues. I personally think the collection interfaces in Java are a big mess, but I'll leave it at this.

Now, if you want a solution to the drawback of `ArrayDeque` not having random access, there are some options:

- First of all, do you really need random access? Perhaps `iterator()` or `descendingIterator()` are good enough.
- For truly random access, this is probably not very fast, but it should be O(1): `deque.stream().skip(index).findFirst().get()`